# Check if a certain key is being pressed?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I need to check if the SHIFT or CTRL keys are being pressed in my VB.net application, any ideas? (get a boolean)

Comment: Do you want if in Console app, WinForms, WPF... Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.aspx#

It's about KeyEventArgs Class with some examples how to detect shift/ctrl keypress etc.

Answer (score 27):

The following will return True or False depending on whether the key is pressed at that moment.  From the wording of your question, I assume you are *not* asking about event handling, which is what the other answers have addressed.

```
My.Computer.Keyboard.ShiftKeyDown
My.Computer.Keyboard.CtrlKeyDown
```

Comment: Very, very cool! I was thinking there had to be some kind of KB object, but was looking under the `Environment` class. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

```
If Control.ModifierKeys = Keys.Shift Or Control.ModifierKeys = Keys.Control Then
    ' Shift, Ctrl, or Shift+Ctrl is being pressed
Else
    ' Neither Shift nor Ctrl is being pressed
End If
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want to see on whole application. To do this, forms or controls have "keypress" or "keydown" events. You can check them with those events. Click events tab and you'll see them