# Execute code during loop after keypress

Tags: vba, excel

I'd like to execute some code whenever I for example press space bar at any time during that loop. Just not sure how to do it.

```
Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
Sub Startvogelpiek()
Dim rngCursor As Range
Dim rgbWit As Long
Dim rgbZwart As Long
Dim lngSnelheid As Long

Set rngCursor = Range("AL5:AX5")
rgbWit = RGB(255, 255, 255)
rgbZwart = RGB(0, 0, 0)
lngSnelheid = Range("AZ8").Value

For aantalkeer = 1 To 20
For teller = 1 To 13
    If rngCursor.Cells(teller - 1).Interior.Color = rgbZwart Then
        rngCursor.Cells(teller - 1).Interior.Color = rgbWit
    End If
    rngCursor.Cells(teller).Interior.Color = rgbZwart

'If **Spacebar_pressed** Then

rngCursor.Cells(teller).Interior.Color = RGB(125,125,125)

Exit Sub

End If

        Sleep lngSnelheid
        If rngCursor.Cells(13).Interior.Color = rgbZwart Then
            rngCursor.Cells(13).Interior.Color = rgbWit
        End If
    Next
    If aantalkeer = 20 Then
        MsgBox ("Uw tijd is afgelopen.")
        Exit For
    End If
    Next

    End Sub
```

Comment: what would cause you to press the spacebar? what is the trigger? Or is that you just want to stop the code execution and be able to determine which line it stopped on (hence the different color)?

Comment: you'll need a separate instance of excel to run a separate monitoring macro or event. The other way is to stop in the middle of the code to check for something and then continue running.

Comment: @area9 I chose to stop in the middle of the code, my code just isn't correct "If **Spacebar_pressed** Then"

Comment: ok, have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5495613/check-if-a-certain-key-is-being-pressed and here: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/keytest.aspx

Comment: Does your macro not run very fast?  If it's a fast macro, how are you going to press the space bar in time?  What determines if you want to press the space bar? I ask because there may be a better trigger to look out for, or perhaps we can use a message box and ask the user if they want the macro to do the equivalent if the space bar was pressed.

Comment: Well as you can see i'm using a function sleep which slows down the macro to whichever speed u like. I'm basically trying to make this minigame, there's a black cell that keeps circling under the colored cells on the right. When you press spacebar it stops circling, the point is to press the spacebar at the right moment so your black cell is under the green cell. https://gyazo.com/4776cb56efa38218fa96655199f8f376

Comment: It's not a "quick tweak" - you're going to have to play with that sleep function, the `DoEvents` command and the `WM_Keydown` Win API or similar